# Shell script - loop through directories?

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, centos, mp4, h.264

If I wanted to loop through a list of nested directories and run a set commands, how would I do that?

My directory structure is like this:

- videos

  - folder1
    -> VTS_01_1.mp4
  - folder2
    -> VTS_01_1.mp4
  - folder3
    -> VTS_01_1.mp4
    .... and so on

I need to loop through each folder and run the script below.. All of the .mp4 files are named VTS_01_1.mp4, but I'd like to do it with a *.mp4 wildcard condition just incase they aren't. The output file in each directory should be "VTS_01_h264.mp4". Ideas? I'm using CentOS 6.4.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "VTS_01_1.mp4" -an -pass 1 -threads 2 -vcodec libx264 -b 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
       -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 \
       -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 \
       -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8 -coder 1 -me_range 16 \
           -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10\
       -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 "video_tmp.mp4"



ffmpeg -y -i "VTS_01_1.mp4" -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 96k -pass 2 -threads 2 -vcodec libx264 -b 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
       -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 \
       -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 \
       -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8 -coder 1 -me_range 16 \
           -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10\
       -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 "video_tmp.mp4"



qt-faststart "video_tmp.mp4" "VTS_01_h264.mp4"
```

Comment: There is no reason for you to declare so many options. That's what the x264 presets are for. You can simplify the command to: `ffmpeg -y -i input -an -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -b:v 512k -f mp4 /dev/null && ffmpeg -i input -pass 2 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -b:v 512k -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -b:a 96k -movflags faststart output.mp4` The first pass output can be sent to `/dev/null`, `-b` is ambiguous so you should specify the stream, and you can replace `qt-faststart` with the `-movflags faststart` option in the 2nd pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` command is very powerful in such things, try:

```
find videos/ -name "*.mp4" -exec ffmpegScript {} \;
```

This finds all files (also in subdirectories) with `.mp4` as ending and executes `ffmpegScript nameOfMp4File`, where `nameOfMp4File` is the name of the file that was found, one at a time. `find` takes care of the looping itself.

Now we need to define the `ffmpegScript`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

inputFile="$1"
outputFile="$(dirname $1)"/VTS_01_h265.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i "$inputFile" -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 96k -pass 2 -threads 2 -vcodec libx264 -b 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
   -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 \
   -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 \
   -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8 -coder 1 -me_range 16 \
       -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10\
   -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 "video_tmp.mp4"

qt-faststart "video_tmp.mp4" "$outputFile"
```

The `inputFile` variable is set as first positional parameter passed to the `ffmpegscript`, the `outputFile` variable is set with the same path, but different `basename`.

Note: This script will overwrite your output files if there's more than one `*.mp4` file in a directory. Also, I didn't try the whole script, since I don't have any `*.mp4` files available here.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

#----------+code----------
find *.mp4 -maxdepth 3 -type f | while read files
do
./ffmpeg.sh "${files}"

qt-faststart "${files}_tmp.mp4" "VTS_01_h264.mp4"
done
#----------.code----------
```

And in ffmpeg.sh:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

#----------+code----------
ffmpeg -y -i "${1}" -an -pass 1 -threads 2 -vcodec \
    libx264 -b 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
   -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 \
   -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 \
   -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8 -coder 1 -me_range 16 \
   -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10\
   -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 "${1}_tmp.mp4"
#----------.code----------
```